# I am using NOT IN but it is slow

Tags: mysql, sql

***CRM* TABLE EXAMPLE:**

```
`crm` example:
+----+--------+---------------------+--------------------+
| id | name   |         date        |      status        |
+----+--------+---------------------+--------------------+
| 1  | john   | 2017-12-27 10:58:10 | A status           |
| 2  | steve  | 2017-12-27 10:58:08 | A status           |
| 3  | eric   | 2017-12-27 10:58:04 | Delivery Arranged  |
| 4  | phil   | 2017-12-27 10:57:55 | A status           |
| 5  | bob    | 2017-12-27 10:57:52 | A status           |
| 6  | foo    | 2017-12-27 10:57:50 | A status           |
| 7  | steven | 2017-12-27 10:57:48 | Delivery Arranged  |
| 8  | paul   | 2017-12-27 10:57:43 | A status           |
| 9  | alex   | 2017-12-27 10:57:31 | Delivery Arranged  |
```

The object of my query is to return the number of `crm` rows where the `status` is *Delivery Arranged*, and the `date` is between `2017-12-01` and `2018-01-01`.

So, here's my main **query**:

```
SET @from='2017-12-01';
SET @to='2018-01-01';


SELECT 
        COUNT(*) AS `delivery_arranged`
    FROM
        `crm` a
    WHERE
        a.`status` = 'Delivery Arranged'
            AND DATE(a.`date`) BETWEEN @from AND @to
```

**RESULT:**

```
+---------------------+
|   delivery_arranged |
+---------------------+
| 30                  |
```

All good. But I want to **discount** those rows that have once before (actually ever, apart from this date range) been set to *Delivery Arranged*. I have a *statuslog* table that I can use for this:

***STATUSLOG* TABLE EXAMPLE:**

```
`statuslog` example:
+--------+-------+---------------------+-----------+---------------------+
|   id   | crmid |        date         |   user    |        status       |
+--------+-------+---------------------+-----------+---------------------+
| 818572 | 1     | 2017-12-27 10:58:10 | johnsmith  | Some status change |
| 818571 | 2     | 2017-12-27 10:58:08 | johnsmith  | Some status change |
| 818570 | 3     | 2017-12-27 10:58:04 | another    | Delivery Arranged  |
| 818569 | 4     | 2017-12-27 10:57:55 | another    | Delivery Arranged  |
| 818568 | 5     | 2017-12-27 10:57:52 | johnsmith  | Some status change | 
| 818567 | 6     | 2017-12-27 10:57:50 | another    | Some status change |
| 818566 | 7     | 2017-12-27 10:57:48 | johnsmith  | Delivery Arranged  |
| 818565 | 8     | 2017-12-27 10:57:43 | another    | Some status change |
| 818564 | 9     | 2017-12-27 10:57:31 | johnsmith  | Some status change |
```

So with this table I can get the rows from `statuslog` that are not between the date range and then do a `NOT IN`:

```
SELECT 
        COUNT(*) AS `delivery_arranged`
    FROM
        `crm` a
    WHERE
        a.`status` = 'Delivery Arranged'
            AND DATE(a.`date`) BETWEEN @from AND @to
            AND a.`id` 
            NOT IN (
            SELECT 
                a.crmid AS `crmid`
            FROM
                statuslog a
            WHERE
                a.status = 'Delivery Arranged'
                    AND DATE(a.`date`) NOT BETWEEN @from AND @to
            GROUP BY a.crmid
            ORDER BY a.`date` DESC
            )
```

This works but depending on the size of the date range it can take ages! `statuslog` has > 2,000,000 rows.

How can I make this query faster?

Comment: The first thing to look at is indexes, have you done that? Then SETS are faster than VARCHARS which are faster then TEXTS.

Comment: Get the bottom of the query execution. Find out the query plan and cost of the query. Look for the join methods it uses. Then accordingly you can drill down the type of indexes you need to filter out the data and possible rewrite the query as @Gordon Linoff  suggested below. But first need to do the homework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Left join may work better than a surrogate subquery:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS `delivery_arranged`
FROM
    `crm` a
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (
        SELECT 
            a.crmid AS `crmid`
        FROM
            statuslog a
        WHERE
            a.status = 'Delivery Arranged'
                AND DATE(a.`date`) NOT BETWEEN @from AND @to
        GROUP BY a.crmid
        --ORDER BY a.`date` DESC --<-- this has no sense
    ) b
  on a.`id` = b.crmid
WHERE
    b.crmid is null and   --<- not int translated to left join
    a.`status` = 'Delivery Arranged'
    AND DATE(a.`date`) BETWEEN @from AND @to
```

Also, remember to use right indexes.

Answer (score 0):

This will usually be faster if you use a `LEFT JOIN`/`WHERE`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS delivery_arranged
FROM crm c LEFT JOIN
     statuslog sl
     ON sl.crmid = c.id AND
        sl.status = 'Delivery Arranged'
        sl.date >= @from AND
        sl.date < @to + INTERVAL 1 DAY
WHERE c.status = 'Delivery Arranged' AND
      c.date >= @from AND
      c.date < @to + INTERVAL 1 DAY AND
      sl.crmid IS NULL;
```

For this version, you want indexes on `crm(status, date, id)` and `statuslog(crmid, status, date)`.

Note that this changes the date comparisons to avoid the function call on the column.  This makes it more feasible to use an index that includes the `date` column.